# How to display my image from the xmlArray?

Tags: xml, swift

[image][image]I got this function, which is a xml file, I wanted to save the image url inside a array and display it at `UIImageView`, but how to do it? Am I doing it in a wrong way?

```
func latestNews(){

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://api.jocom.com.my/feed", parameters: ["req" : "news"])

        .responseData { response in

            print(response.request)  // original URL request

            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            let xmlLatestNews = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!)
            print(xmlLatestNews)


            for elem in xmlLatestNews["rss"]["channel"]["item"]{

                let latestNewsImg: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100, self.latestNewsScrollView.frame.size.height))
                latestNewsImg.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()


                let thumbnailURL = NSURL(string: (elem["thumbnail"].element!.text!))

               //self.xmlArray is a NSURL array  (var xmlArray = [NSURL]())

                self.xmlArray.append(thumbnailURL!)


                self.latestNewsScrollView.addSubview(latestNewsImg)
            }


           print(self.xmlArray)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's many items that were returned from the server, I would normally create a model object to store those properties. In your case, if it's just URL. I would store it as String array.

```
var stringURLArray = [String]()
stringURLArray.append(elem["thumbnail"].element!.text)
```

Then just retrieve back the string and show the image

```
let stringURL = stringURLArray[indexPath.row] as? String
let url = NSURL(string: stringURL)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
cell.yourImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

To assign to particular image as example.

```
    let imageView1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50))
    let stringURL = stringURLArray[0] // you can choose which index you want
    let url = NSURL(string: stringURL)
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    imageView1.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView1)
```

To create a loop and add image programatically:

```
    var position: CGFloat = 0.0

    for urlString in (stringURLArray).reverse()  {
        let imageView1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0 + position, 0, 200, 50))
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString) //
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
        imageView1.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        self.view.addSubview(imageView1)
        position += 200 // space out the width of each image
    }
```

Comment: im not displaying it in a tableview, is just a normal view, i wanted to display it in a image scroll view. how to do it? This is the function that i will be call at viewdidload()

Comment: if there are many images, you can do a for loop on the array to display in your image scrollview after you append all elements inside the response completion handler

Comment: can you show me how? sorry, im very new to all this, and your help is very much appreciated

Comment: sure but need to know more information from your side. how many images you want to show? and how do you create your image scrollview? and other information that i might missed out

Comment: i updated my question with the screenshot, you can see the output area there the last line return the images array that i save that needed to display, around 5 images url. my scrollview i created at main storyboard and my imageview i created using code, which i added as a subview

Comment: i see. ok. i updated with new code. does this answer your question?

Comment: i wanted to display all the images out and the scrollview can scroll horizontally to view all the images

Comment: i see. ok. i update with new code for that you can create image programatically

Comment: i just updated with the screenshot, it displayed but then the position i dont know why it space out so much, and the images display start from index5, it display from the backwards

Comment: sorry i wrongly put extra position there. i update the code. use reverse if you want to sort array in reverse